# Azure Queue Trigger is not executing with Isolated Worker Process

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, queuetrigger

I have created a Queue Trigger function. As mentioned in the microsoft docs, I also added packages "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker", "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" but project is not building, and giving error "Specified condition "$(SelfContained)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean" in package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets. Please see my csproj file below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="SD.Dentaflows.Models" Version="1.1.10" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This is my Program.cs class code and My function class code and my main purpose is to use methods of "RequestQueueWritebackHandler" in my function.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configBuilder) =>
            {
                configBuilder.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<RequestQueueWritebackFunction>();
                services.AddSingleton<IRequestQueueWritebackService, RequestQueueWritebackHandler>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}

public class RequestQueueWritebackFunction
{
    private readonly IRequestQueueWritebackService requestWritebackService;

    public RequestQueueWritebackFunction(IRequestQueueWritebackService requestWritebackService)
    {
        this.requestWritebackService = requestWritebackService;
    }

    [FunctionName("RequestQueueWritebackFunction")]
    public void Run([QueueTrigger("%RequestWritebackQueueName%", Connection = "WritebackConnectionString")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

        var result = requestWritebackService.SaveRequestWritebackMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create local.settings.json like below:
And make change from **WritebackConnectionString** to **AzureWritebackConnectionString**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "StorageConnectionString",
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "StorageConnectionString",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWritebackConnectionString": "QueueConnection"
  }
}
```